# Check a checkbox using HttpPost (from HttpCommons)

Tags: java, checkbox, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'd like to check a checkbox with HttpPost. As far as I understand I need to create a NameValue pair and then set is as the entity for the post.
My question is what is the name and the value for checking a checkbox? I saw that a checked checkbox has the attribute 'checked' with no value so I tried this: `new BasicNameValuePair("checked", null)` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to myself:
basically, read about html first. But for the question: If you want to check a checkbox all you have to do is send a name value pair for it, corresponding to the name of the checkbox, and the value of the checkbox (if it has), so for example if our checkbox is like this: `<BR><INPUT type=checkbox NAME="ok" VALUE="yes">Ok?`
 so you should post this NameValuePair : `new BasicNameValuePair("ok" // name of checkbox , "yes" //value of checkbox)`
end of story.